# KL-divergence between two categorical/multinomial distributions gives negative values?

Tags: information-theory, kullback-leibler

If

$$P = [0,0.9,0,0.1]$$

$$Q = [0,1,0,0]$$

Then $$KL(P||Q) = 0 + \ln(0.9/1)\cdot0.9 + 0 + 0 = -0.094$$

This shouldn't be possible from the Gibbs inequality. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let’s remove the two categories with probability $0$ in both distributions. Your example is $P = (0.9, 0.1)$ and $Q = (1,0)$.

The KL divergence is $KL(P||Q) = \sum_i p_i \log\left( {p_i \over q_i }\right)$. It is not 
$$ 0.9 \times \log\, 0.9 + 0 $$
but 
$$ 0.9 \times \log\, 0.9 + 0.1 \times ( +\infty ) = + \infty.$$

Comment: @Elvis If there are 0's in an array .. how are we supposed to handle that situation?

Comment: If two discrete distributions with same support are both 0 at some point of this support, you can just remove this point, as I did above.